# Do not run the IntegrationFlow when spring batch remote chunking worker application starts

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-batch, spring-integration

i am new to spring integrarion and batch and i want to develop a remote chunking batch application with a master and worker . I used spring integration and RabbitMQ for message queue, the application runs fine but the worker itemProccessor start automaticaly, however i need to controle when to start it.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableBatchIntegration
@EnableIntegration
public class WorkerConfig {


    @Autowired
    private RemoteChunkingWorkerBuilder<Integer, Integer> remoteChunkingWorkerBuilder;

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel requestsChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow inboundFlow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory,"requests"))
                .channel(requestsChannel())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel repliesChannel() {
        System.out.println("repliesChannel 3 ");
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow outboundFlow(AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(repliesChannel())
                .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(amqpTemplate).routingKey("replies"))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Integer, Integer> itemProcessor() {
       ....
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Integer> itemWriter() {
       ...
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow workerIntegrationFlow() {
        return this.remoteChunkingWorkerBuilder
                .itemProcessor(itemProcessor())
                .itemWriter(itemWriter())
                .inputChannel(requestsChannel())
                .outputChannel(repliesChannel())
                .build();
    }


}
```

So what i can do to manualy start the worker part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the adapter an `id` and set auto startup to false.

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow inboundFlow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory,"requests")
                .id("inbound")
                .autoStartup(false))
            .channel(requestsChannel())
            .get();
}
```

Then `@Autowire` the adapter and start it...

```
@Autowired
AmqpInboundChannelAdapter inbound;

...
    inbound.start();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for response , but i think that it works only with inboundPolledAdapter not inboundAdapter

Comment: I think that i missed something , because in complile time it gives me that : "Cannot resolve method 'from(org.springframework.integration.amqp.dsl.AmqpInboundChannelAdapterSMLCSpec, <lambda expression>)'" .any sollution please

Comment: Sorry, my mistake; the `id` and `autoStartup` go directly on the adapter spec - see the edit.

Comment: Thanks , now it is good , but i get the folowing error : "required a bean of type 'org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter' that could not be found" ...  if you could show what is wrong plz, thank you very match

Comment: That doesn't make sense; the integration flow registers the bean with the id as its name. You might need to add `@DependsOn("inboundFlow")` to the bean where you are auto wiring the adapter.

Comment: I solved it by creating a AmqpInboundChannelAdapter @Bean and pass it to IntegrationFlows.from(ampqInboundAdapter(connectionFactory)) ... Thank you very match , your assitance was a life saving Mr Russell